# Understanding stringstream

Tags: c++, string, c++11, sstream

I have never used stringstream before and was given a sample code but with no explanation of what was happening in the code. If someone could explain each line's purpose that would be great. I have looked in multiple places but cant seem to pin down the second line.

```
#include <sstream> // i know this line includes the file

stringstream    ss(aStringVariable);// this line in particular 

ss >> aVariable;

getline(ss, stringVariable2HoldValue, ‘|’);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a constructor for `std::stringstream` that takes a `std::string` as a parameter and initializes the stream with that value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::stringstream ss("foo bar");

    std::string str1, str2;
    ss >> str1 >> str2;

    std::cout << "str1: " << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str2: " << str2 << std::endl;

}
```

This code initializes a `stringstream`, `ss`, with the value `"foo bar"` and then reads it into two strings, `str1` and `str2`, in the same way in which you would read from a file or `std::cin`.